# How to allow a custom local node_module to navigate project file system?

Tags: node.js, local-node-modules

I have a linked local custom node_module that needs to use the projects file directory: /tmp in order to dump a file there during run time. How can I direct my custom node_module to this directory?

I have tried accessing root using nodes internal path utility but this just stays within the node_modules folder.

Trying to access tmp folder by using:

```
var root = require('find-root')(path.resolve(__dirname));
this.tmpDir = path.resolve(root, 'tmp');
```

Outputs:

```
"/Users/me/Documents/Project/Billing/server/node_modules/processremote/tmp"
```

But I need it to navigate (back out of) to:

```
"/Users/me/Documents/Project/Billing/server/tmp"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find-root` returns the directory of the closest `package.json`, which in your case is the directory of the child module itself (since it has a `package.json` file and is closest to the script).

You can fix this by using `path.join(root, '../..', 'tmp')` (instead of the current `path.resolve(root, 'tmp')`):

```js
var root = require('find-root')(path.resolve(__dirname));
this.tmpDir = path.join(root, '../..', 'tmp');

// `tmpDir` will now be "/Users/me/Documents/Project/Billing/server/tmp"
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks @Itai Steinherz exactly what I was looking for.